# Multi-Sig for those wallets who are used to send tokens in and out

Tags: gnosis-safe

We are going to launch a DeFi project and chose Gnosis to use multi-sig but I have some questions.

As every project has top wallets so we have, which includes **marketing wallet, treasury wallet, and rewards wallet.**

We will first create a Gnosis Safe for our rewards wallet so it will be called as rewards safe.

Then our rewards safe will have a big bag of our tokens and will be integrated with our smart contract and it will be used to receive tokens in and send out tokens to users.

Will it work? How will smart contract send tokens in and out without multi sig?

If it's not possible then does it mean we can only multi sig those safe's which will be operated only by signers and not through any smart contract?

Looking forward!

Answer (score 0):

There wouldn't be any problem with sending the tokens to the Rewards Safe. However, to send the tokens out of the Safe, the signers must confirm each individual transaction or a MultiSend transaction that sends the tokens to multiple accounts.

The Safe allows to expand its functionality with [modules](https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/4934378-what-is-a-module) that are ruled by custom logic and can bypass all the signature checks required when executing Safe transactions.

A module could be called by an external contract to execute transactions, but take into account that modules are very security-critical.

Here there are a couple of [examples](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-modules).